# AlphaTensor code for a model can discover new algorithms for solving quadratic equations

Tags: python, installation, deep-learning

Help me, I ask to CHAT GPT about "alpha tensor code for a model to discover new algorithms to solve quadratic equations" and this is the answer:

[code from chat gpy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEUDP.png)

When trying the code I get the error: "No module named 'alpha_tensor_tf'". The problem is that I can't find the AlphaTensor library

how to install alphatensor library

Comment: What makes you think it's a library? That's not how to interpret the error message or that corresponding import statement.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. ChatGPT isn't a reliable tool. There are multiple reported cases where ChatGPT "hallucinates" (include nonsenses / stuff that doesn't exists). It might be helpful but use it together with the best reference material that you can get access.

Comment: ChatGPT is a language model. It is made to respond like a human would. It can write well, but the actual info isn’t reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe alpha tensor is an AI developed by Deepmind. I think is been based on the chess model alphazero, go model alphago, etc etc... Here is some information about it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7V4E_GK1dt8. Mybe there is an API to call the AI on your enviroment? I don´t know.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).